# Proper format for MusicEvent using microdata from Schema.org

Tags: events, schema.org

I'm a bit confused as to how i properly format a MusicEvent using a schema from schema.org. The fact, that I#m not a native english speaker doesn't make understanding the docs not easier too...

The docs say i should use `itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event"` for an Event.

But theres also a MusicEvent on schema.org, see here http://schema.org/MusicEvent

So does this mean, i should use `itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event/MusicEvent"` or what?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you should use MusicEvent. At the top of the MusicEvent page on schema.org you'll see some breadcrumbs that look like this:

Thing > Event > MusicEvent

This means that the MusicEvent type includes the Event type which includes the Thing type. The page also lists all the properties from Thing and Event that can be used for a MusicEvent. There are currently no properties which only apply to MusicEvent so its just there to tell search engines what sort of event it is.

Answer (score 0):

You should use MusicEvent but your syntax is in error.

When a more specific type is a available for a named type, you simply declare that itemtype, rather than the type, rather than that itemtype and the more general ("parent") itemtype.

This is incorrect:
    itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event/MusicEvent"

This is correct:
    itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MusicEvent"